# Calculate the percentage of the groups compared to the total

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have the following schema :

[image]

I am using a live connection to this SSAS Tabular cube, I want to calculate the % of the Products with Status = Available

for each product comparing to the total of Products with Status=Available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
% Products Available = 

VAR NumProductsAvailable = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactTable[ProductSK] ),
        Status[Status] = "Available"
    )

VAR NumProducts = 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactTable[ProductSK] )

RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        NumProductsAvailable,
        NumProducts
    )
```